# Does Liferay require the Jikes compiler?

Tags: liferay, java, jikes

All Liferay docs seem to suggest that it is necessary to install the Jikes compiler in addition to the JDK. Is this really needed, to do Liferay portlet dev, or can I just suffice with the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

No. As far as I know Jikes was never a strong dependency. It used to be a default compiler for older releases of Liferay. But since version 4.4 [they changed](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Jikes) to standard javac.

Answer (score 1):

No. We have Liferay 5.2.3 running in a production environment. We've done a few customizations of the liferay core as well as new portlets.

I never installed the Jikes compiler, the JDK was sufficient for every task.

Answer (score 0):

The last two years at least, we've been predominantly building with ecj, which is much, much faster than any JDK compiler I've ever used.

In your `build.${user.name}.properties` specify

```
javac.compiler=org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter
```

Comment: I'd say that happens because ecj is incremental :)